# "Could not login to FTP server" during Maven Ant task – But can login in GUI FTP client using the same credentials

Tags: maven, ant, ftp, digital-ocean

I have a Maven build where once the packaging is complete, I attempt to send some files from the packaging to an FTP server using a specific profile. The problem is, I consistent get a Maven failure whenever I try this:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run 
(deploy) on project xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: An Ant BuildException has occured: 
Could not login to FTP server
```

This is quite confusing because I am able to log into the FTP server using FileZilla and the same credentials I am using for the Maven Ant build task without any problems (on the same machine). I am also able to transfer files in both directions via FileZilla without any problems either.

This used to work fine before I did a routine server restart recently. My FTP server is a DigitalOcean droplet with the standard Ubuntu OS and VSFTPD installed.

My `pom.xml` is as follows:

```xml
...
<profile>
  <id>publish-product</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>deploy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <ftp
                    server="${env.DEPLOY_FTP_SERVER}"
                    remotedir="${env.DEPLOY_FTP_DIR}"
                    userid="${env.DEPLOY_FTP_USERNAME}"
                    password="${env.DEPLOY_FTP_PASSWORD}"
                    umask="002"
                    passive="yes">
                        <fileset dir="target/repository">
                        <include name="**/*" />
                    </fileset>
                </ftp>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          </executions>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                  <artifactId>ant-commons-net</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.9</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
<profile>
...
```

The Maven build is executed using:

```
mvn -U -DskipTests clean package -Ppublish-product
```

*Does anyone know what might be happening to prevent the Ant FTP task from running?*

The full output of the Ant task is as follows:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (deploy) on project xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx: An Ant BuildException has occured: Could not login to FTP server -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (deploy) on project xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx: An Ant BuildException has occured: Could not login to FTP server
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: Could not login to FTP server
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AbstractAntMojo.executeTasks (AbstractAntMojo.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute (AntRunMojo.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Could not login to FTP server
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP.execute (FTP.java:2528)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute (UnknownElement.java:288)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute (DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform (Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute (Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AbstractAntMojo.executeTasks (AbstractAntMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute (AntRunMojo.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

The detailed log of my FileZilla session is as follows:

```
Status: Resolving address of myftpserver.xxxx.xxxx
Status: Connecting to 218.86.381.231:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
Status: Connection closed by server
Status: Resolving address of myftpserver.xxxx.xxxx
Status: Connecting to 218.86.381.231:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
Status: Resolving address of myftpserver.xxxx.xxxx
Status: Connecting to 218.86.381.231:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Starting upload of D:\logo.pdf
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 1,260 bytes in 1 second
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
Status: Calculating timezone offset of server...
Status: Timezone offset of server is 0 seconds.
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
Status: Deleting "/logo.pdf"
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Connection closed by server
Status: Resolving address of myftpserver.xxxx.xxxx
Status: Connecting to 218.86.381.231:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
Status: Connection closed by server
Status: Resolving address of myftpserver.xxxx.xxxx
Status: Connecting to 218.86.381.231:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Starting upload of D:\logo.pdf
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 1,260 bytes in 1 second
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Could not login to FTP server"* error indicates that your credentials are wrong. The error is issued when [`FTPClient.login`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#login(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) fails.

I see that you have validated that you have the correct credentials by authenticating with a GUI FTP client. So chances are that there are some special characters in the credentials that may need some escaping or special treatment.

Answer (score 0):

One may face a similar problem when the FTP server is using TLS. The Ant plugin does not support FTPS.